# Average access time with cache misses

Tags: caching

The memory access time is 1 nanosecond for a read operation with a hit in cache, 5 nanoseconds for a read operation with a miss in cache, 2 nanoseconds for a write operation with a hit in cache and 10 nanoseconds for a write operation with a miss in cache. Execution of a sequence of instructions involves 100 instruction fetch operations, 60 memory operand read operations and 40 memory operand write operations. The cache hit-ratio is 0.9.What is the average memory access time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is to find the time taken for,
  "100 fetch operation and 60 operand red operations and 40 memory operand write       operations"/"total number of instructions".

Total number  of instructions= 100+60+40 =200

Time taken for 100 fetch operations(fetch =read)
    = 100*((0.9*1)+(0.1*5)) //1 corresponds to time taken for read when there is  cache hit
    = 140 ns                //0.9 is cache hit rate

Time taken for 60 read operations
    =60*((0.9*1)+(0.1*5))
    =84ns

Time taken for 40 write operations
    =40*((0.9*2)+(0.1*10))  =112 ns
//Here 2and 10 the time taken for write when there is cache hit and no cahce hit respectively

So,the total time taken for 200 operations is = 140+84+112=336ns

Average time taken = time taken per operation=336/200= 1.68 ns